# node-red - Credentials not saved after a restart

Tags: credentials, node-red

I have to test a flow against my MQTT broker and database. I have the flow file but not the credentials file as I will be providing mine. So, in my `settings.js` I set `flowFile` to this flow JSON document and also set `credentialSecret` to some string. In the flow, I deleted/added new credentials and deployed.

Then, I restarted Node-RED as `pm2 restart red` and launched the editor. I get the error as shown attached below.

[image: Credentials could not be decrypted]

The credentials are blanked out too.
[image: Blank credentials]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart node-red after making changes to the `settings.js` and before making the changes to the flow?

Comment: `settings.js` was changed when node-red was stopped. Launched node-red, made changes to credentials, deployed and then, restarted node-red.